# With batch script. Copy a file from one directory to another, then prompt me what to rename it to

Tags: batch-file

As the title explains.

With batch script. Copy a file from one directory to another, then prompt me what to rename it to.

If a similar file already exist in the target directory, then just replace/overwrite it.

Can I write something like this in batch script?  I know how to copy from one directory to another.  But the second part I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Why do you want a prompt for the new name? You can take the new name as a command-line argument. And in that case, you don't need a script at all; the builtin `copy` command can already do everything you want in one go, e.g. `copy /y srcdir\oldname.txt destdir\newname.txt`.

Comment: Hi
If I can explain it this way,  The file I would like to copy, gets generated by a different software.  It is a simple text file.  It always creates the same filename, but the contents is different.  I would like to copy that file by running the script, to the new directory and then it must ask me what the file should be named.  If the name already exist, it must overwrite it.  This is a tool I will use all the time.  Hope this explains it better.

Comment: Currently I'm doing it manually.  Copy the file in the source directory, paste it in the target directory and then rename it to what it should be.  But first I have to delete the existing file if there is one, before I can rename the copied one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
@echo off
set "oldFile=C:\someDirectory\test.txt"
set "newDirectory=C:\someOtherDirectory\"
set /p "newFile=Please enter a filename for the new file: "
copy /y "%oldFile%" "%newDirectory%%newFile%"
```